# Parsing response returned by mediawiki api

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, mediawiki-api

PS - Scroll down to the bold italic thing for my question; everything else is context

The program is pretty simple (which makes how long I've struggled with every aspect of it even more embarrassing) ; html form takes an input from the user; queries the media wiki api using that input as the search query, gets the response.

I've gotten this much to work, & I can render the whole Json object media wiki returns.

[image]

From here I can access the value for the "pages" key.

[image]

[image]

But this is not easily readable, so I need to figure out how to index each of the keys separately, store those values in some JS object, & then I can display things in a normal way.

***However this is proving more difficult than I'd have thought. Below are a bunch of things I tried. Any ideas on both how to parse this Json object & why the below things failed?***

Things that did not work

```
this.answer = data.pages.excerpt
```

```
this.answer = data.pages
this.ans_spec = this.answer.excerpt
```

Both of the above resulted in "benign failures" where this.answer / this.ans_spec were undefined

```
this.answer = JSON.parse(data.pages)
```

```
this.answer = data.pages
this.ans_spec = JSON.parse(this.answer)
```

These properly caused the JS block to fail & go to the catch block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.pages` is an array of objects, so you just need to loop over it:

```
for (const page of data.pages) {
    console.log(page.id);
    console.log(page.excerpt);
    // ...etc
}
```